# Sign using cross sign

Tags: windows, kernel, driver, code-signing-certificate

Why signing works but signing verification doesn't ?

> signtool sign /v /ac comodorsacertificationauthority_kmod.crt /tr http://timestamp.comodoca.com/rfc3161 mydriver.sys

```
The following certificate was selected:
    Issued to: Company, Inc
    Issued by: COMODO RSA Extended Validation Code Signing CA
    Expires:   >..
    SHA1 hash: ....

Cross certificate chain (using machine store):
    Issued to: Microsoft Code Verification Root
    Issued by: Microsoft Code Verification Root
    Expires:   Sat Nov 01 16:54:03 2025
    SHA1 hash: 8FBE4D070EF8AB1BCCAF2A9D5CCAE7282A2C66B3

        Issued to: COMODO RSA Certification Authority
        Issued by: Microsoft Code Verification Root
        Expires:   Mon Apr 12 01:16:20 2021
        SHA1 hash: 106870659C069F248C8C0A05ACD871CABEB3CC38

            Issued to: COMODO RSA Extended Validation Code Signing CA
            Issued by: COMODO RSA Certification Authority
            Expires:   Mon Dec 03 02:59:59 2029
            SHA1 hash: 351A78EBC1B4BB6DC366728D334231ABA9AE3EA7

                Issued to: Company, Inc
                Issued by: COMODO RSA Extended Validation Code Signing CA
                Expires:   ...
                SHA1 hash: ...

Done Adding Additional Store Successfully signed: mydriver.sys
```

> signtool verify  /v  /kp  mydriver.sys
>
> Signature Index: 0 (Primary Signature)
>       Hash of file (sha1): 1EDBB6F9354413D1B0F1696BF713281954F75130
>
> ```
> Signing Certificate Chain:
>     Issued to: COMODO RSA Certification Authority
>     Issued by: COMODO RSA Certification Authority
>     Expires:   Tue Jan 19 02:59:59 2038
>     SHA1 hash: AFE5D244A8D1194230FF479FE2F897BBCD7A8CB4
>
>         Issued to: COMODO RSA Extended Validation Code Signing CA
>         Issued by: COMODO RSA Certification Authority
>         Expires:   Mon Dec 03 02:59:59 2029
>         SHA1 hash: 351A78EBC1B4BB6DC366728D334231ABA9AE3EA7
>
>             Issued to: MyCompany, Inc
>             Issued by: COMODO RSA Extended Validation Code Signing CA
>             Expires:   ...
>             SHA1 hash: ...
>
> The signature is timestamped: Thu Oct 25 16:17:01 2018
> Timestamp Verified by:
>     Issued to: UTN-USERFirst-Object
>     Issued by: UTN-USERFirst-Object
>     Expires:   Tue Jul 09 21:40:36 2019
>     SHA1 hash: E12DFB4B41D7D9C32B30514BAC1D81D8385E2D46
>
>         Issued to: COMODO SHA-1 Time Stamping Signer
>         Issued by: UTN-USERFirst-Object
>         Expires:   Tue Jul 09 21:40:36 2019
>         SHA1 hash: 03A5B14663EB12023091B84A6D6A68BC871DE66B
>
> SignTool Error: A certificate chain processed, but terminated in a root
>     certificate which is not trusted by the trust provider.
>
> Number of files successfully Verified: 0
> Number of warnings: 0
> Number of errors: 1
> ```

Comment: Do you have the root cert in the Windows keystore in the machine?

Comment: I have everything to sign correctly.
Comodo support pointed me that I should use /pa switch instead of /pk , but this is not what they write on their web page.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use verify /ds 1 /v?? Where /ds 1 is index 1, not 0?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/framework/tools/signtool-exe